# Change defaults of build in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines

I have a several builds defined in Visual Studio Team Services

[image]

However, each time I queue one up, it asks me to set some variables.
[image]

How do I change the defaults in this box?  I tried putting "/p:TargetProfile=Dev" into the MS Build Arguments input on the build definition, but the defaults didn't change.  I need both "release" and "Cloud" as highlighted above to be "Dev"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you edit your build definition, go to the variables tab you can change the defaults there. You can also specify whether or not you want these variables to be displayed when queuing build.
Hope that helps.
Cheers

Comment: Didn't even see that.  Thanks so much!